# How to create type with constants properly with Flow in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I am creating types for React application with Flow. I am not sure how is the right way to do this.

I want to have constant for the possible entries in the type which can I access afterwards (as enum) and I want the type to contain the constant instead of literal.

```
// @flow

export const CARD_TYPE = {
 firstType: 'one',
 secondType: 'two',
};

export type CardType = {
 type: CARD_TYPE,
};
```

I expect that I will be able to use the CARD_TYPE as constant in my components, and the CardType as type, but I get the following error:

Flow: Cannot use object literal as a type because object literal is a value. To get the type of a value use `typeof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. You should be able to do the following

```
// @flow

export const CARD_TYPE = {
 firstType: 'one',
 secondType: 'two',
};


export type CardType = $Keys<typeof CARD_TYPE>
```

here's a [codepen of the solution with no errors](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCmAPADrATgF1AMawB2AzvgMICCASgCID6AKgJoAKAoqALygDeiUJACW2ckwCeGFAC5QAchIp5AGkGkURYgBNJ0ufNzxYqxAF8A3MlSYc+XFJSgKAQ2y7HPUABIA0iglSAB4HaVhIZ1pGVk4APmQtciFRcjlXdz0nXnkRMVxM+URE-A0tbTS3D2kveVKSKuUgA)